# com.sun.net.HttpServer load

Tags: java, rest, http, httpserver

I'm using the lightweight server provided in [oracle java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) since java 1.6 and I'm using just to receive POST responses from another server.

Now for 2 or 3 responses it run well but when the load is increased I'm not receiving all the responses from the server, some of them are ignored.

I tried to increase the `backlog` to 1500 but it's the same thing.

here's how I create the server :

```
public class HttpServerZipWhip {

    private final String SERVER_IP_ADDRESS = "X.X.X.X";
    private final Integer SERVER_PORT = 9333;
    private final short SERVER_BACKLOG = 1500;
    private final String SERVER_CONTEXT = "/message/receive";


    /**
     * Constructor : Server initiation
     * @param muc
     * @param smshandle
     */
    public HttpServerClass(Muc muc, SMSHandling_impl smshandle){

        //Server Initialization
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
        HttpServer server = null;

        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(addr, SERVER_BACKLOG);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        server.createContext(SERVER_CONTEXT, new MyHandler(muc, smshandle));
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging or troubleshooting? Please share what you have discovered so far.  We cannot possibly help since we do not have access to your specific configuration, and if you want help you are going to do most of the troubleshooting yourself.  Try adding logging statements to your server to track what is happening.

Comment: Actullay I'm wondering if the server can handle like 100 requests in a row or not. And I did some debugging but I'm trying to find a way to see the full incoming requests that aren't in the handle pool but I can't to seem to find a way